# sql unique constraint with parents

Tags: sql, postgresql

In postgres 9.5, I have this sql constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT gp_property_name_unique UNIQUE (name, parent_id, active)
```

This works but only if parent_id is not null. How can I make sure that the name field is unique if it is a root field? (=> parent_id is null)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may add a unique index like:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX gp_property_name_unique_parent 
ON your_table(name, active) WHERE parent_id IS NULL;
```

This index is only for rows where the `parent_id` is `null`. Since it is unique it works like the requested constraint. In fact, unique constraints in postgres are based on unique indexes.

Comment: I can confirm this worked like a charm for me. Very elegant. Thx